# Unable to load config file in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, fatal-error, php-5.4

I'm new to PHP and smarty, I don't know how to solve this. This is a rough idea about my project directory

MyProject

```
->include
->configs->site.conf
MyProject ->include->config.php
MyProject ->libs->smarty->plugins
MyProject ->libs->smarty->sysplugins
MyProject ->libs->smarty->debug.tpl
MyProject ->libs->smarty->Smarty.class.php
MyProject ->libs->smarty->SmartyBC.class.php
MyProject ->presentation->templates->test.tpl
MyProject ->presentation->templates_c
MyProject ->presentation->application.php
MyProject ->index.php
```

I have defined a variable in my site.conf file. SITE_TITLE. I'm trying to load my config file in **test.tpl** like this.....

```
{$smarty->configLoad('site.conf')}
```

I also tried this....

```
{config_load file='site.conf'}
```

But I'm getting this error....

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 
'Syntax Error in template "E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\presentation\templates\test.tpl"
on line 1 "{$smarty.configLoad('site.conf')}" $smarty.configLoad is invalid' 
in  E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\libs\smarty\sysplugins
\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
:656 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\libs\smarty\sysplugins
\smarty_internal_compile_private_special_variable.php
 (93): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase-
 >trigger_template_error('$smarty.configL...') 
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\libs\smarty\sysplugins
\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
(473): Smarty_Internal_Compile_Private_Special_Variable
->compile(Array, Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), 
'['configLoad']', NULL, NULL) 
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\libs\smarty\sysplugins
\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
(247): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase
->callTagCompiler('private_special...', Array
, '['configLoad']') #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\Cel 
in E:\xampp\htdocs\Project\libs\smarty\sysplugins
\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 656
```

**config.php is this....**

```
define ( 'SITE_ROOT', dirname ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) ) );
define ( 'PRESENTATION_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/presentation/' );
define ( 'BUSINESS_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/business/' );
define ( 'SMARTY_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/libs/smarty/' );
define ( 'TEMPLATE_DIR', PRESENTATION_DIR . 'templates' );
define ( 'COMPILE_DIR', PRESENTATION_DIR . 'templates_c' );
define ( 'CONFIG_DIR', '/include/configs' );
```

**application.php is this...**

```
require_once SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php';

class Application extends Smarty {
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct ();

    $this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_DIR;
    $this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
    $this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
}
```

}

**and this is my index.php...**

```
require_once 'include/config.php';

require_once PRESENTATION_DIR . 'application.php';

$application = new Application ();

$application->display ( 'test.tpl' );
```

I'm using PHP 5.4.16 and smarty 3.1.10

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you're supposed to call `$smarty->configLoad('site.conf')` from *inside* a template like that.

Comment: I would recommend to set the directories like this: `$this->setTemplateDir(TEMPLATE_DIR)->setCompileDir(COMPILE_DIR)->setConfigDir(CONFIG_DIR);`

Answer (score 3):

`$smarty->configLoad('site.conf')` goes to your application.php not the template file.

If you are using this function in .tpl file you can do it like this

```
{config_load file="site.conf"}
```

Reference: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.config.load.tpl

**Edit:**
check if the path is correct. try

```
{config_load file="../../configs/site.conf"}
```